# How to create two XORable lists from a main list in python?

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation, byte

I have a list of ASCII bytes in binary for the word 'test'

```
1110100 1100101 1110011 1110100
```

How can I create two additional lists, so that when I do XOR operation between them, I get the list above?

For example I have first bin file, which contains one list, and another bin file which contains the second list.

Decoding lists in both files gives the resulting array above.

Answer (score 0):

Have one file be the list you want to generate, and the other all zeros.

Comment: That wouldn't be unique then and very easy to guess. I was thinking some binary generation considering the necessary XOR output.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that "hard to guess" was a requirement. Maybe having the first list be random bits and the other the first bit xor the target list works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create random bytearray (list), it would be your 1st file.
Thereafter, you XOR your 1st file with target "list", and receive 2nd file.

When you XOR 1st and 2nd files, you will get back your original file.

More formal (f1=first file, f2=2nd file, M=message):

```
f1 = R
f2 = R ^ M
M = f1 ^ f2 = R ^ R ^ M
```